# Unlink image based on url variable

Tags: php, image, unlink

code updated!!
I am trying to delete image from certain folder + data from database.
so far it deletes database data, however it is no unlink'ing the image together with database data...script piece as follows :

```
          // echo '<pre>'; var_dump($row_rs_galleries);exit;
    $path=$_get[$row_rs_galleries['gallery_image']];
    $file="../uploads/gallerytitle/resized/$path";
    unlink($file);

$deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM galleries WHERE gallery_id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['gid'], "int"));
```

echoing out array it shows:

```
array(4) {
  ["gallery_id"]=>
  string(2) "20"
  ["gallery_name"]=>
  string(9) "sdvsdvsdv"
  ["gallery_image"]=>
  string(27) "resized_140959609221730.JPG"
  ["image_alt"]=>
  string(8) "dsvsdvsd"
}
```

It is deleting data from database but still not unlinking the image...Path seems to be ok, Array as well..What could be the problem?

The whole page code here (in case i am placing unlink function in a wrong place?)

```
<?php require_once('../Connections/conn_hell.php'); ?>
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
$colname_rs_galleries = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['gid'])) {
  $colname_rs_galleries = $_GET['gid'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_conn_hell, $conn_hell);
$query_rs_galleries = sprintf("SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE gallery_id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rs_galleries, "int"));
$rs_galleries = mysql_query($query_rs_galleries, $conn_hell) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rs_galleries = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs_galleries);
$totalRows_rs_galleries = mysql_num_rows($rs_galleries);
if ((isset($_GET['gid'])) && ($_GET['gid'] != "")) {
    //--------------------------The unlink----------------------------------------------------------
//echo '<pre>'; var_dump($row_rs_galleries);exit;

    $path=$_GET[$row_rs_galleries['gallery_image']];
    $file= realpath(__DIR__ . "../uploads/gallerytitle/resized/$path");
     unlink($file);
 //-----------------------------------------------End unlink

$deleteSQL = sprintf("DELETE FROM galleries WHERE gallery_id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_GET['gid'], "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_conn_hell, $conn_hell);

  $Result1 = mysql_query($deleteSQL, $conn_hell) or die(mysql_error());

  $deleteGoTo = "../announcments.php?aid=5";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $deleteGoTo .= (strpos($deleteGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $deleteGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $deleteGoTo));
}
 ?>
<?php
mysql_free_result($rs_galleries);

?>
```

Comment: This sounds like a permissions issue. If your are running linux, you might need to check your apache user (usually www-data) has proper permissions on the folder you are trying to delete files from.

Comment: Thanks.Well i am running windows.I think permissions should be ok as i am able to upload images to given folder..I guess that problem is in this piece of code : $path=$_GET[$row_rs_galleries['gallery_image']];
    $file="../uploads/gallerytitle/original/$path";
    unlink($file);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a relative path in the file that you want to delete, maybe that is the problem

Try using [`realpath`](http://php.net//manual/es/function.realpath.php) function with `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__` to retrieve the absolute path of the file

If you have php verion < 5.3

```
$file= realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . "../uploads/gallerytitle/resized/$path");
```

php version => 5.3

```
$file= realpath(__DIR__ . "../uploads/gallerytitle/resized/$path");
```

Also I recommend to check if the file exists before delete it

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    unlink($file);
}
```

**EDIT**

Why are you using this?

```
$path = $_GET[$row_rs_galleries['gallery_image']];
```

Instead of

```
$path = $row_rs_galleries['gallery_image'];
```

Comment: Tried it, but for some reason the file is still there...Maybe i am putting unlink function in the wrong place? I will post all code i have on that page, maybe you could have a look and tell me if thi is where it should be..(if file exists not implemented yet)

Comment: If I checked it correctly then nothing.. added print in front of that line and opened in browser- nothing...tried to delete file through website , also shows blank page

Comment: changed code according your directions.Still something wrong..image is still in the folder.any more ideas?Thank for helping out btw

Comment: print `$totalRows_rs_galleries` also are you testing it with the `gid` query? like `index.php?gid=NUMBER_HERE`

Comment: it's already deleted because it's does not checks if the file is deleted

Comment: I cannot print it on time properly as when i supply gid variable it automaticlly deleting data in database..however before every test, i created new gallery.so there is a row which fits gid every time.

Comment: Thanks for your help! this worked perfectly fine now!$path=$row_rs_galleries['gallery_image'];
$file="../uploads/gallerytitle/resized/$path";

if (file_exists($file)) {
 unlink($file);
}

Comment: Glad to help! You could accept this as answer, click in the chckmark in the left of this answer

Answer (score 0):

I advise you that don't put query strings on url, and this code it's a little bit messed and it can embarrass the code's debug, but wherever, the problem can be in array $row_rs_galleries, before the

```
$path=$_GET[$row_rs_galleries['gallery_image']];
```

you can put it to see what the array is returning:

```
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($row_rs_galleries);exit;
```

and now, you can see what's going on with the identifiers and the values from this array. :D